Refresh UI in MAUI when changing from portrait to landscape
I saw other posts about this topic but their are not recent. The issue is when you have a .NET8 MAUI page and you change the orientation of your device, MAUI is not refreshing the UI.
Here an example. My application starts as portrait

Then I change the view as landscape

Then I change to portrait again and the page is like that

How can I force the refresh of the page for iOS and Android?

What do you mean by saying "refreshing"? Do you need to re-render the entire page?

Yes, because the page changes margin and its shape but doesn’t resent them

You have available triggers in xaml: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/triggers?view=net-maui-8.0#adaptive-trigger

Try to use InvalidateMeasure()?

You can try the following code:
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfoChanged += Current_MainDisplayInfoChanged;
}
 
private void Current_MainDisplayInfoChanged(object? sender, DisplayInfoChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.DisplayInfo.Orientation==DisplayOrientation.Portrait)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Portrait");
        MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => 
        {
            InvalidateMeasure();
        });
    }
}

